# I thought he would have been

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, future-perfect

> a. I thought he would have been sad before I entered the room and seeing me would make him happy. Actually, he was happy and seeing me made him sad.

> b. I thought he would have felt sad before I entered the room and seeing me would make him happy. Actually, he was happy and seeing me made him sad.

> c.  I thought he would have been feeling sad before I entered the room and seeing me would make him happy. Actually, he was happy and seeing me made him sad.

> d. I thought he would be sad before I entered the room and seeing me would make him happy. Actually, he was happy and seeing me made him sad.

I think (d) is the best and (c) is grammatically correct, but convoluted. Is that correct?

Comment: What happens if you — instead of `I thought ...` — use the verb `I expected ...`? Will that open up new possibilities?

Comment: They're all syntactically valid, but stylistically the use of "conditional" modal auxiliary ***would*** in the first three is ***awful***. Stick with the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Each of example sentences a, b, c, and d is grammatically valid. Each is reasonably understandable by a fluent speaker. However the construction "* I thought he would have* used in a thru c is in my view awkward, at least in this context. I would avoid it. d however, is in my view a bit confusing as to whether it is referring to a past event or not.  I would be inclined to rewrite this into something more like:

> e. I expected him to  be sad before I entered the room and that seeing me would make him happy. Actually, he was happy and seeing me made him sad.

This expresses the same thought as the examples. I think it is clearer. Other versions are quite possible. There is no one "correct" or "best" version.